# BASH script not working on windows

Tags: bash, script, shell-script

So I made a bash script, that works on MAC perfect, but on windows even with cygwin and CURL installed doesn't work, here is the errors that I'm getting

```
$ ./r.bash

Project name:
imiodrag
': not a valid identifiertheme_name
: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `\r': File exists
>>>>>>>>>>Downloading wordpress...

Warning: Failed to create the file latest.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
158   158    0   158    0     0    531      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   531
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8)
tar (child): latest.tar.gz\r: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
rm: cannot remove `latest.tar.gz\r': No such file or directory
>>>>>>>>>>Moving files...

mv: cannot stat `start-project/wp-base/': No such file or directory
: No such file or directorycontent/themes/
: No such file or directoryib/
>>>>>>>>>>Now downloading jquery...

Warning: Failed to create the file jquery-latest.min.js
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  1 93436    1  1127    0     0  17888      0  0:00:05 --:--:--  0:00:05 17888
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1127)
: No such file or directory./
' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        init
' did not match any files

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Lili@Lili-PC.(none)')
: No such file or directory./../../
```

And here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo ""
    echo "Project name: "
    read theme_name
    cd "../"
    mkdir "$theme_name"
    cd "$theme_name"
    echo ">>>>>>>>>>Downloading wordpress..."
    echo ""
        curl -O http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
        tar --strip-components=1 -zxf latest.tar.gz
        rm latest.tar.gz
    cd "../"
        echo ">>>>>>>>>>Moving files..."
        echo ""
        mv start-project/wp-base/ "$theme_name/wp-content/themes/$theme_name"
        cd "$theme_name/wp-content/themes/$theme_name"
    cd js/lib/
        echo ">>>>>>>>>>Now downloading jquery..."
        echo ""
      curl -O http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
    cd ../../
        git init
        git add .
        git commit -a -m "First commit"
    cd ../../../../
    rm -rf start-project
```

So why isn#t working on windows?any advices? I'm on windows 7 64bit ultimate

Comment: Try using Unix line endings.

Comment: can you be more specific please? thank you

Comment: Use a text editor (e.g. Notepad++) and save your bash script with [Unix line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations). I don't know how to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin requires Unix line endings, as has already been noted. So instead of ending each line with Carriage Return Line Feed (CRLF), you need to end each line with just a Line Feed (LF) AKA Newline.

Many text editors allow you to convert the line endings. Cygwin itself can convert the file using the command line tool `d2u`.